# solving wave equation by fourier transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

in solving wave equation by Fourier transform after taking fourier transform of wave equation $$\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial^2x}=\frac{1}{v^2} \frac{\partial^2y}{\partial t^2}$$ we get $$(-ia)^2 Y(a,t)=\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{d^2Y(a,t)}{dx^2}$$
this is ok. now how we can get to this: $Y(a,t)=F(a)e^{(+-)ivat}$

tanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**: Rearrange your expression to yield $(va)^{2}Y(a,t)+\frac{d^{2}Y(a,t)}{dt^{2}}=0$.

Comment: so now the descriptor equation is $r^2+(va)^2=0$ and this yield to $Y(a,y)=F(a)(e^{ivat}+e^{-ivat})$ and this equals to $Y(a,t)=F(a)(e^{(+-)ivat})$. i am right?